# Triggering a form event from inside a custom control

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, custom-controls

I've created a user control that contains a number of text boxes, labels and buttons.

Inside that custom control there are custom handlers that deal with lostfocus and textchanged in order to do formatting and bad input prevention.

As part of the lostfocus handler there is a check to see if the amount entered is too large an either prevents the user from exiting the textbox or for the 5 textboxes which have a related button fires the buttons click event.

```
    Public Sub txtLostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)

    Dim txt = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Dim sAmtText As String = txt.Text

    If sAmtText <> "" Then
        If txt.Tag = "Money" Then

            sAmtText = sAmtText.Replace(",", String.Empty)
            sAmtText = sAmtText.Replace("$", String.Empty)

            If Val(sAmtText) > 999999.99 Then
                MsgBox("The amount you are trying to enter is too large.")

                Select Case txt.Name
                    Case "txtNetSales"
                        btnNetSalesBreak_Click(sender, e)
                    Case "txtCdnCash"
                        btnCashBreak_Click(sender, e)
                    Case "txtCheques"
                        btnChequesBreak_Click(sender, e)
                    Case "txtCredit"
                        btnCreditBreak_Click(sender, e)
                    Case "txtFloat"
                        btnFloatBreak_Click(sender, e)
                    Case Else
                        e.Cancel = True
                End Select
            Else
                txt.Text = FormatCurrency(txt.Text)
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Within the custom control itself this works fine.

In my Forms App I've added about a dozen of these and I'm looping through the controls inside them to create generic handlers.

```
    For Each pnl As Control In cs.Controls
        For Each ctrl As Control In pnl.Controls
            Select Case ctrl.GetType()
                Case GetType(Button)
                    AddHandler ctrl.Click, AddressOf ButtonClick
                Case GetType(TextBox)
                    AddHandler ctrl.KeyPress, AddressOf txtKeyPress
            End Select
        Next
    Next
```

However while the click even on the form does what it needs to do, the click event raised inside the custom control does not seem to be hitting the handler inside the form. (which for now is just a message box with the buttons name)

Also if I put a message box inside the custom control then the code runs only the custom controls click even on lostfocus but Clicking the button itself triggers both the one inside and outside.

So is it at all possible for an event being called from inside a custom control to interact with an even created outside of it and if so what am I doing wrong?

Or will I have to move my lostfocus code outside the control?

Any input would be appreciated.